# Looping limited Objects in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects which I'm able to loop it this way:

```
for(const key of Object.keys(this.arrayOfObjects)) {
  this.id[key] = this.arrayOfObjects[key].id
}
```

But, I wanted to know if there is a way where I can only loop objects of specific range. For example, I want to loop from 'i'th object to 'k'th object of existing array of objects.

Comment: You may do `for(const key of Object.keys(this.arrayOfObjects).slice(x,y)){...`

Comment: Why not just use `for (let i = start; i < end; i++) { // this.arrayOfObjects[i] }`? Also, for arrays, you don't need to do `Object.keys()`. You can `for(const item of this.arrayOfObjects)` will get each object in `item` variable